# Calculating circular radius given chord length and perpendicular height to arc

Tags: geometry, circles

I was searching for a solution to a very practical problem asked by a friend of mine. The problem was that he had to lay a dropped kerb to allow vehicular access to customer's property... except the kerb was on a road bend. Since I am the closest person that he knows to qualify as a civil engineer, so he asked me to find a formula that could be used for this purpose. In the image is a diagram with workings to create the final formula for the unknown radius. My question is this: Is the formula and derivation universally correct? [image: arc-chord length radial derivative formula]

My result was $$r=\dfrac{4B^2+A^2}{8B}$$
Where B is the perpendicular height from midpoint of arc to midpoint of chord and A is the length of the chord itself.

I am concerned that I introduced an error in part 2 of the 3 steps of evaluation. Can anyone refute this?

Comment: Maybe but my question is whether my answer I  have formulated is correct. Since there is nobody available to help me locally I decided to ask the community.

Comment: Compare yours to the many solutions in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't read your photo, but by the title you have a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).  The Wikipedia article has 
$$R=\frac {c^2}{8h}+\frac h2$$

Comment: That doesn't look anything like what I have

Comment: $c$ is the distance between the endpoints of the arc and $h$ is the distance from the perpendicular height.

Comment: c is the chord length (your A) and h is the arc segment height (your B).  so in your variables, R=A^2/8B+B/2, and over your common denominator, R=(A^2+4B^2)/8B.  So yes, your formula is correct.  Nice work!